# Sencha Touch list and scrollToRecord

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a long sencha touch list and I am trying desperately to scroll that list into somewhere in the middle on startup.

The function

```
btnScroll:function() {
    var list = Ext.getCmp("myList");
    var position = 4;
    list.scrollToRecord(list.getStore().getAt(position));
}
```

works if I tap the button: `scrollBtn.setHandler(btnScroll);`, but it does not work in

```
MyList.constructor:function() {
    ...
    this.callParent();
    this.btnScroll();
}
```

It just fails without error message. Same goes if I do it in the calling function:

```
btnOpenList:function() {
    var list = new MyList();
    list.show();
    list.btnScroll();
}
```

It works sometimes(!) if I use `setTimeout(this.btnScroll,70);` instead, but never if I use `setTimeout(this.btnScroll,50);` or `setTimeout(this.btnScroll,120);`

I think it happens because the list elements are not rendered/positioned. But I did not find any afterrender event.

So how would I define a scroll position in which the list should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in painted event. just add to your list or  to container that contains all components that u need to bind the painted event.. and then get your list there and add event to btn.. or whatever you want.. by the template:

```
element.clearListeners();
element.addListener('tap',function(){
    //...
});
```

Comment: I am trying to play around in a fiddle, to demonstrate my problem to you, but I don't even get it how to display the list in the fiddle. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4nj